# If given the coefficeints, standard errors and r^2, how can I determine overall significance of an OLS model?

Tags: statistical-significance, least-squares, r-squared, coefficient-of-variation

Basically the title. Say I am given coefficients 1,2,3 and standard errors .1, .02, .01 respectively and an R^2 value of 0.35. How would I go about testing the overall significance of the model?

Comment: Do you have the sample size?

Comment: @Firebug No I do not